# sending jstring from jni c code to a java function that receives string as an argument

Tags: java, c, string, java-native-interface

How do I send a `jstring` from JNI `C` code to a `Java` function that receives a `String` as an argument ?

I have read about the functions like `callVoidMethodA(....)` but they do not accept anything such as a `jstring`.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned the target class name and the target method signature. So consider, for example, [java.lang.StringBuilder.append(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
// First lets assume you have already received the next variables
void foo( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj )
{
    // Call StringBuilder.append() method
}
```

Now you need the class name and the method signature (according to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html))

```
static char const StringBuilder_ClassName = "java/lang/StringBuilder";
static char const StringBuilder_append_MethodName = "append";
static char const StringBuilder_append_MethodSignature =
    "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;";
```

To call java method from JNI code you should obtain `jmethodID`

```
static jclass StringBuilder_Class = 0;
static jmethodID StringBuilder_append_Method = 0;

void Init( JNIEnv* env )
{
     if( StringBuilder_Class == 0 ) {
         StringBuilder_Class = (*env)->FindClass( env, StringBuilder_ClassName );
         // TODO: Handle error if class not found
     }
     if( StringBuilder_append_Method == 0 ) {
         StringBuilder_append_Method = (*env)->GetMethodID( env, StringBuilder_Class,
             StringBuilder_append_MethodName, StringBuilder_append_MethodSignature );
         // TODO: Handle error if method not found
     }
}

void foo( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj )
{
    Init();
    char* str;
    // str = ...;
    jstring jString = (*env)->NewStringUTF( env, str );
    // Because StringBuild.append() returns object, you should call CallObjectMethod
    jobject ret = (*env)->CallObjectMethod( env, obj, jString );
    // Here you can release local references, i.e.
    // (*env)->DeleteLocalRef( env, ret );
    // (*env)->DeleteLocalRef( env, jString );
    // But it is not necessary. Local references are released automatically when
    // thread returns from JNI code to Java code.
    // So you can ignore the returned value and not to release the jString local
    // reference, i.e. just call
    // (*env)->CallObjectMethod( env, obj, jString );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
 Java_Prompt_getLine(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
 {
     char *buf = "Hi !!!!";
     jstring jString = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
     free(buf);
     return jString;
 }
```

Comment: I want to send it as an argument as stated in the question